# Vista to Vista network visability issue

Tags: windows-vista, networking

I've got a Vista Business PC and a Vista Business Laptop connected via a virgin media router (Netgear CG2100D) and I cannot get the two machines to see each other correctly over the network.
The laptop is connected via wireless, whilst the pc is wired.
Both are set to recieve their network settings automatically (DHCP) and both have the windows firewall (the only firewall on either) turned off completely.

I can ping each machine fine from one another using the ip addresses,
and I can also connect via \.
However, connections via \ fail, and I cannot see the machines in the network map.

I have tried turning netBIOS to be "always on" on both adapters, but this makes no difference.

I've been messing around pretty much for 6 hours now and am getting quite fustrated by this! (my original aim was to get media sharing working, but I've pretty much abandoned that for now).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is down to the new CG2100D router supplied by Virgin Media.
I'm unsure as to what exactly in the router configuration is causing it, but replacing it with the previous Netgear router completely resolves the issue